# Error Expected , or ;, but got WHEN en VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Hola soy algo nuevo en VHDL, se me pidió hacer un registro pipo de 4 bits cuyo resultado pasaba a un deco de 4 bits, el pipo(flipflop D => Qn == Qn) y el deco por separado funcionan, pero cuando los uni marca error de sintaxis o con palabras reservadas, intente cambiar el tipo de seleccion para el deco pero no funciono, este es el codigo:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity pipo is
   port(
       clk,rst : in std_logic;
       din : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       Q : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end pipo;

architecture funcionamiento of pipo is
signal D : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal Qn : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
begin
  pipo_p : process(clk,rst,din)
  begin
    if(rst = '1') then
        D <= "0000";
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        D <= din;
    end if;
 end process pipo_p;

 deco_p : process(D,Qn)
 begin
  with D select Qn <= 
     "1111110" when "0000",
     "0110000" when "0001",
     "1101101" when "0010",
     "1111001" when "0011",
     "0110011" when "0100",
     "1011011" when "0101",
     "1011111" when "0110",
     "1110000" when "0111",
     "1111111" when "1000",
     "1111011" when "1001",
     "0000000" when others;

Q <= Qn;
end process deco_p;

end funcionamiento;
```

Y el error es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea 26 es donde empieza el "with D select Qn <=" y la 27 ya es la seleccion de los bits para el deco